# Compile error: libicui18n.so.54 needed by libQt5Core.so.5 not found

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, gcc

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> //头文件
using namespace cv; //包含cv命名空间

int main()
{
    Mat img=imread("cornea.jpg");
    imshow("src",img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

And I compile it with:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs opencv
```

Which gives me:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.54, needed by //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)<br/>
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.54, needed by //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)<br/>
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicudata.so.54, needed by //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_clone_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘uenum_next_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘u_strToLower_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getStandardName_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_setAttribute_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_setMillis_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_strcoll_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_setSubstChars_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_getTimeZoneDisplayName_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_openCountryTimeZones_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_fromUnicode_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_open_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getDefaultName_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_open_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_close_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_inDaylightTime_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_getSortKey_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getAvailableName_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_close_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_get_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_openTimeZoneIDEnumeration_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_getDSTSavings_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_open_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_openTimeZones_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_toUnicode_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘u_strToUpper_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘u_errorName_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_close_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘uenum_close_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_countAvailable_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getMaxCharSize_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getAlias_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_getDefaultTimeZone_54’未定义的引用<br/>
//home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_compareNames_54’未定义的引用<br/>
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The backticks in command line `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs opencv` is invisible. I have not got the reason now.

Indeed,in early days, I have installed Qt. But now, I do not want my program have something to do with Qt. In order that my program is not affected by the Qt library function, I shielded the path variables of Qt in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file and installed a new gcc of 5.3.0. But the same error is still existing!

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4):

Download ICU-54.1 from here
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.7/general/icu.html
and install manually.
For me this solved the problem.

Comment: My friend, I have uninstalled my Qt5 and installed a new opencv 3.1.0. But also failed! Open the link of the error: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884832/compile-error-undefined-reference-to-atomic-fetch-add-4)

Comment: The link to icu package is good.  I have looking for it and thanks for putting the link here.