# Compile error : undefined reference to‘__atomic_fetch_add_4’

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, gcc

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  Mat img=imread("cornea.jpg");
  imshow("src",img);
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

And I compile it with:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

or

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv -I/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/include -L/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/lib -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -lpng -lz -ltiff -ljasper -ljpeg -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lfreetype -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -ldc1394 -lv4l1 -lv4l2 -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt
```

Which gives me:

> /tmp/ccoZCMRO.o：in function‘cv::Mat::release()’：main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x22)：undefined reference to‘__atomic_fetch_add_4’
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am using opencv 3.1.0 in the terminal of ubuntu 14.04 in VM!

Comment: There is probably a more interesting root cause to unearth, but have you tried `-march=native` or `-latomic`?

Comment: Many thanks to you, my friend! Both `-march=native` and `-latomic` are useful! And could you please tell the root cause about it?

Comment: You need some implementation of atomic operations. i386 did not have suitable atomic instructions, so on those you need a library implementation (in libatomic). If you let the compiler know that you are actually interested in a more recent machine than i386 (say i686) then it can directly use the appropriate instruction and you don't need a library.

Answer (score 3):

On i386, you need to add `-latomic` as GCC cannot use assembler instructions but has to fallback on the libatomic library implementation.

Starting with i586, atomic instructions are available and linking against libatomic is no longer required. That means, the alternative of `-latomic` is to use `-march=i586`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing Debug and Release versions of the OpenCV libraries. https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5581
You should only include and link against the normal Release library, or againt a Debug library you built yourself.

In your case, this may come from the double include `-cflags -I /usr/local/include/opencv`. I would try remove all the manual paths and just write `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` (to the packaged Release version).

Note that `/usr/local/include` is a standard include path and will always be searched. You could try to exclude standard paths with `-nostdinc` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Another option is to uninstall one of the two versions, or remove one version away from the standard paths.

Comment: My friend,when I use `g++ -o main main.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs opencv``, the same error occurs! My PKG_CONFIG_PATH links to a file named opencv,pc. The opencv.pc contains version information, compiling and linking parameters.

Comment: You may still link the wrong library because `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib` are always searched, and the former takes precedence. I think it is still worth trying to remove your own compiled version (the /usr/local one) to a non-indexed folder or uninstall the packaged version, to make sure you are including and linking one and the same version.

Comment: I think you words make sense. When I installed opencv 3.0.0, I just I just referred to the official website without caring about the installation path `/usr/local`. Of course, The fundamental reason is I do not really understand it. **Can you tell me how to uninstall opencv?**. I am afraid of deleting something else incorrectly.

Comment: hello, this time I have installed opencv 3.1.0, but one of the error still exists as mentioned in the question! Do you konw how to solve it?

Comment: @LittleTooth, I edited my answer. Besides this, removing libraries from /usr/local means either running `make uninstall` or manually looking at all the files there and deleting them by hand (because you have no bookkeeping information which library they belong to).

Comment: But if I `make uninstall` in `/usr/local`, I am afraid I will delete something else incorrectly, for example, some softwares installed by default. So far, I have moved the files with `*opencv*` from `/usr/local` to my personal file and installed a new opencv 3.1.0 in `/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to link with atomic library. Try with

-latomic

in your GCC compilation command line.

NOTE: i had to do it compiling with CLang 8 on a ARMv7 device (Android).

Comment: For those adding `-1` please provide feedback for others