# undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_4 error while using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I'm new to opencv library and every time i try to compile This code

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Mat img;
img = imread("lena.jpg");
imshow("Original Image", img);
waitKey();
}
```

I get This error ***undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_4***

This code is copied from a tutorial and It's was working with its writer so the problem is definitely with me

I looked for a solution for this problem to much and I did not found any working solution, I do not even no what is the cause of the problem

I'm using Code::Blocks IDE

Thanks,

Comment: obviously, you haven't linked the .lib(windows) file or .so/.a(linux) file

Comment: @anuniquemonkey no, befor linking i was facing another error, after linking opencv libraries i got this error

Comment: try to add link atomic lib "-latomic"

Comment: @anuniquemonkey i cant find it, where does it exists?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35884832/2079934 please see my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35889268/2079934

Comment: Yes, looks very much like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35884832/2079934 . Same error message and practically the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setting>Compiler Settings and tick the Intel i486 option. It worked for me