# Build error when installing opencv-python on raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, pip, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install the opencv-python module on my Raspberry Pi 4, with Raspberry Pi OS. I am using a version of python 3.11 which I installed myself (using [this tutorial](https://raspberrytips.com/install-latest-python-raspberry-pi/), and not changing the default version), and I made a virtual environment to work with safely. But when I try to install the opencv-python module with pip, it fails after 2-3 hours (I think, but I haven't actually timed it) of building, with [this error message](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vPYOJXllvCY7QXo4fOuwSGeBzdhbqeYi/view?usp=sharing) (I just piped the stdout and stderr of the `pip install opencv-python` command to a file).

I have looked on the internet, but haven't found this same problem, although I found some other problems from other people trying to build opencv-python on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Please don't link to private cloud drive but only share relevant debugging information directly in your question. What exactky did you try? Did you check similar things like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884832/compile-error-undefined-reference-to-atomic-fetch-add-4?

Comment: Looks like your Raspberry Pi OS is 32 bit version. OpenCV compiles only on 64-bit arm64

Comment: @Markus Sorry for using Google Drive, the file was too long to put in the body of the post. Yes I checked these "similar things", but none seemed to help.
@maciek It's weird because when I run `uname -m` it says `aarch64`, so here did you see my OS is 32-bit ?

Comment: This took 5 minutes w/out compiled. Here is link https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got my answer, thanks to @maciek, who told me opencv only compiles on 64-bit arm64. My Raspberry Pi’s CPU is 64-bit, but I had installed the 32-bit version of Raspberry Pi OS (because it is default on Raspberry Pi Imager). So I did a clean install of the 64-bit version of the OS on my machine after saving my files, and then reinstalled the latest Python version as an altintall (as I did before), and then retried like before, and it worked.